# VS Code debugging causes Python subprocess to hang

Tags: python, subprocess, vscode-debugger

Debugging Python in VS Code a subprocess starts from futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.  When launch.json specifies `"subProcess": true,` the debugging process hangs and does not complete, but when setting `"subProcess": false,` debugging works as expected.  Why does setting `true` cause futures subprocess to hang and setting `false` work?

Comment: Your question is kind of an answer in itself - at least it helped me :)